# Binding and ForEach in master-detail system

Tags: swiftui

I have an app for macOS which essentially provides an editing function to a set of files which are structured as a bundle. So the idea is to provide a master list which presents each of the files, represented as elements of an array. Clicking on one brings in the detail pane, which allows the user to edit it.

So my UI is structured around a `NavigationView` with a `List` which uses `ForEach` to generate the list in the master column. I keep track of the selection via a `@State` variable in the container view. The trouble I'm seeing seems to be due to passing a binding to the relevant array element into the detail/editor view.

Editing works fine, the problem is that deleting the last element when it is selected leads to an out of bounds failure which doesn't give a helpful trace (it points to the `@main` line).

I've looked at other discussions of this sort of issue, but haven't been able to see a solution. I am aiming to support macOS 11 and up, so cannot move to `NavigationSplitView`.

Here's a simplified version of my code, leaving some details out that aren't (as far as I am aware) relevant.

```
struct MyItem: Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    ...
}

class MyDocument : ... {
    var items: [MyItem]
    ...
}

struct Items: View {
    @ObservedObject var document: MyDocument
    @State private var selectedItem: MyItem? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ItemList(itemList: $document.items, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemList: View {
    @Binding var itemList: [ItemData]
    @Binding var selectedItem: MyItem?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let item = selectedItem, let index = itemList.firstIndex(of: item) {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ItemEditor(item: $itemList[index]),
                    tag: item,
                    selection: $selectedItem) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
             }
             ListOfItems(itemsList: $itemList, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
             Button("-") {
                if let item = selectedItem {
                    document.removeItem(withInfo: item
                    selectedItem = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListOfItems: View {
    @Binding var itemList: [ItemData]
    @Binding var selectedItem: MyItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(itemList) { item in
                Text(item.name)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        if selectedItem == item {
                            selectedItem = nil
                        }
                        else {
                            selectedItem = item
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
}

struct ItemEditor: View {
    @Binding var item: MyItem

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
For completeness, here is the revised version:

```
struct MyItem: Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    ...
}

class MyDocument : ... {
    var items: [MyItem]
    ...
}

struct Items: View {
    @ObservedObject var document: MyDocument

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ItemList(itemList: $document.items)
            Text("No selection")
        }
    }
}

struct ItemList: View {
    @Binding var itemList: [ItemData]
    @State private var selectedItem: MyItem?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ListOfItems(itemsList: $itemList, selectedItem: $selectedItem)
             Button("-") {
                if let item = selectedItem {
                    document.removeItem(withInfo: item
                    selectedItem = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ListOfItems: View {
    @Binding var itemList: [ItemData]
    @Binding var selectedItem: MyItem?
    
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selectedItem) {
            ForEach($itemList) { $item in
                NavigationLink(destination: ItemEditor($item), tag: item, selection: $selectedItem) {
                    Text(item.name)
            }
        }
}

struct ItemEditor: View {
    @Binding var item: MyItem

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `index` anywhere with SwiftUI is considered unsafe. Just check the binding itself.

```
if let b = Binding($selectedItem) {

    NavigationLink(
                destination: ItemEditor(item: b),
                tag: item,
                selection: $selectedItem) {
                    EmptyView()
                }

}
```

You should also watch Demystify SwiftUI. It seems like you have pickup several “workarounds” people use when they don’t understand SwiftUI.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it now gives me an unhelpful crash whenever I click the - button to delete the currently shown item, with no error message in the console, and the pointer at @main.

Comment: @Mussau without a “working” sample it’s impossible to help. Like I said there are many suspicious parts with your code that could be the cause.

Comment: I'd also appreciate it if you could point me to what bad habits I've picked up! SwiftUI was such a paradigm change for an old programmer like me, especially as I do this very part-time and have been working on this for on and off for about 3 years.

Comment: @Mussau indicies, empty view, passing both the list and selected item raises red flags. Basically selectedItem is a second source of truth since you are dealing with value types and you are intermingling them.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've looked at Demystifying SwiftUI, which didn't tell me much new. I guess that I need to rethink the structure again, after the various byways I've found from other authors to solve problems that have since had better solutions.